# cannot set up Selenium Server [Book: Agile Web Application Devlopment with Yii 1.1]

Tags: selenium, yii, selenium-rc

I am following Agile Web Application Development with Yii 1.1

> In chapter 3, page 46.

**Problem 1 :** To install selenium server I typed on cmd (I'm using Window 7)

```
[font="Courier New"]java -jar selenium-server.jar[/font]
```

It ran, but after that, it did nothing else (see figure attached, the forum not allow link)

**Problem 2:** I cant find find `[protected/tests/phpunit.xml]`
`[/protected/tests/unit/]` folder is still empty

Please show me how to solve these issues. Also, anyone can give me the link to any full tutorials to setup environment for Yii such as install `PEAR`, `PHPUnit`, Selenium RC (aka Selenium Server), ... I've just done with PEAR installed

Thanks

Comment: When u say nothing happens, what does that mean? What exactly are u expecting to happen?